# Java - Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I have some questions about implementing the Singleton Pattern in Java.

1. There is a chance of having multiple instances of a Singleton when we use cloning. Is there a specific way we can prevent it?
2. What will be the impact if we are creating another instance of a singleton using serialization & deserialization?

Comment: If other instances could be created, this is not singleton. If you need to clone or serialize *state* of singleton, use special object that reflects its *state* and perform clone/serialization on it, not singleton itself.

Comment: No, that's the whole idea.  Write the singleton so those can't happen.  But think about not writing Singletons.  Google prohibits them: https://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/

Answer (score 2):

1) Do not make Singleton Cloneable and nobody will make a clone of it

2) If Singleton is Serialiazable and it does not use readResolve to prevent duplicates you will get duplicates while deserializing it and it will not be a Singleton anymore. Impact depends on the application logic

Answer (score 1):

Effective Java Item 3:
Elvis is your class.

```
public class Elvis {
  private static final Elvis INSTANCE = new Elvis();
  private Elvis() { ... }
  public static Elvis getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }
  public void leaveTheBuilding() { ... }
}
```

If you want to serialize it:

```
// readResolve method to preserve singleton property
private Object readResolve() {
// Return the one true Elvis and let the garbage collector
// take care of the Elvis impersonator.
   return INSTANCE;
}
```

Or you could use enum:

```
 // Enum singleton - the preferred approach
 public enum Elvis {
   INSTANCE;
   public void leaveTheBuilding() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your second point, but this answers the first one:

```
public class SingletonObject {

    /**
     * The one and only instance of this class
     */
    private static SingletonObject ref;

    /**
     * Creates the object. Must not be called more than once.
     */
    private SingletonObject() {
        // no code required
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the singleton object
     * @returns The singleton object
     */
    public static synchronized SingletonObject getSingletonObject() {
        if (ref == null) {
            // First call, so create it
            ref = new SingletonObject();
        }
        return ref;
    }

    /**
     * Prevents cloning of the object.
     * @throws CloneNotSupportedException If method is called
     */
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException(); 
    }
}
```

You can simply override the cloning method.
Note that `getSingletonObject` is synchronized, which prevents to instances of the object to be created if `ref` equals `null` and two threads call the function at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Evgeniy Dorofeev comment, I do not see any reason to make it cloneable and expecting it to be a singleton as well. For whatever reason if it implements Cloneable you can always throw an exception by overriding clone() method.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a chance of having multiple instances of Singleton when we use cloning. Is there a specific way we can prevent it?

Don't *implement* `Cloneable` interface. You will automatically get `CloneNotSupportedException`when you try to call `clone()~ on it.

2. What will be the impact If we are creating another instance of singleton using Serialization & De-serialization?

Yes, you can create *multiple* versions of your singleton class using *Serialization*. to prevent this don't implement `Serializable` interface or if you want to *explicitly* prevent serialization, you could override `writeObject()` to throw Exception during Serialization.

Code :

```
   // Double check Singleton   
class Singleton implements Serializable {

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
            throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Serialization is not allowed");
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6022571167467223517L;

    private volatile static Singleton singletonInstance = null;

    private Singleton() {

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (singletonInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (singletonInstance == null) {
                    singletonInstance = new Singleton();
                }

            }
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }

}
```